# How to fire a callback after a line has been drawn between 2 points?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have the following points in my spline chart:

[image]

I am trying to invoke a callback function after a line has been drawn between 2 points.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/p50fs7Ld/) is what I have worked on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <figure class="highcharts-figure">
            <div id="container"></div>

            <div class="imFlex">

            </div>
        </figure>

        <style>
            .imFlex { display: flex; flex-direction: row; }
        
                .imFlex > h1 { border: 1px ridge black; padding: 1rem; background-color: lightgrey; font-weight: bold; margin-right: 10rem; }
        </style>
        
        <script>
            var chart;
            var isTesting = true;
            var timestamp;
        
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    events: {
                        load: function () {

                        }
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: ' EVERY BET TAKEN FOR THE PAST 5 MINUTES '
                },
                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: ' TIMEFRAME FOR THE BETS '
                    },
                    type: 'datetime'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
        
                        text: ' NUMBER OF USER BETS '
                    },
                },
                tooltip: {
                    crosshairs: true,
                    shared: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    spline: {
                        marker: {
                            radius: 4,
                            lineColor: '#666666',
                            lineWidth: 2
                        }
                    },
                    series: {
                        animation: {
                            duration: 300000,
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: "Random",
                    data: [5, 8, 9, 50, 34]
                }]
            };

            function UpdateUI(){
                var increment = 1;

                var intervalInstance = setInterval(function(){
                    console.log(increment + " minutes passed");
                    increment++;

                    if(increment >= 5)
                    {
                        clearInterval(intervalInstance);
                    }
                }, 60000);
            }
        
            //Initialize chart
            $(document).ready(function () {
                UpdateUI();
                chart = Highcharts.chart("container", options);
            });
        
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

The problem with the above code is that the line does not take exactly 1 minute to render. I need a callback function that will trigger after a line joins 2 points. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The default easing function used in Highcharts is `easeInOutSine`. This caused an uneven distribution of animation for points.
You can easily fix this by setting `animation.easing` option for a linear function. You use four-time segments, so need to set `animation.duration` to 240000ms.

```
series: {
  animation: {
    duration: 240000,
    easing: function(x) {
      return x
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0fn5hjrm/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting animation duration, you can add points in every interval. The final result is slightly different, but it is a more precise solution.

```
chart: {
  events: {
  load: function() {
    let chart = this,
      i = 1;

    function addPointToSeries() {
      console.log(i + "second passed");
      chart.series[0].addPoint(data[i]);
      i++;
      if (i === data.length) {
        clearInterval(addPoints)
      }
    }

    let addPoints = setInterval(addPointToSeries, 1000);
  }
  }
},
```

**Simplified demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3csma8wg/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint

Comment: Thank you. Any idea why animation duration is not precise?

Comment: Hi! I've added another answer which seems to be more relevant. Regards!